# asynchronous update of a WMS layer in Openlayers

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, openlayers, geoserver

I have a WMS layer on Openlayers map. This WMS layer is showing the position of some person on the map. So, the layer needs to be updated as the person moves. If I call the redraw() function of WMS layer at some predefined time interval, it is updated properly. But the problem is: at every time interval, there is a blinking of the WMS layer. I want to solve this.

Is there any way to update the WMS layer like ajax or any asynchronous way so that the user will not feel that at every time interval, something is happening  internally unnecessary. Any other alternative is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally could get through the problem. I could not find any way to achieve this by WMS layer. Rather I could achieve this with Vector layer.

Now I have a vector layer with the Refresh strategy as follows:

```
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), 
                                 new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({ interval: 5000,
                                     refresh: function() {
                                         myVectorLayer.refresh({force:true})
                                     }

                                  })
            ]
```

This  will help to refresh the vector layer 'myVectorLayer' to refresh every 5 sec.

I hope this will help to any future problem solver.